# Parsing multiple text files with alternate file names, finding sum, and then compiling output with Batch file

Tags: parsing, batch-file, text

**Edited with user recommendations:**

I have a script that I run on thousands of servers that compiles keywords from logs and outputs how many times they occur within a text file. The output looks like this for every individual server:

```
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.001: 0
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.002: 0
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.003: 2
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.004: 0
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.005: 1
```

The last number after the colon is the number of times the keyword is present in the log file. So I have a result file from thousands of servers where I then utilize xcopy to move to my box into the same folder.

After moving the files to my box, I have a script that removes all data after the colon, and then finds the sum. It works, to an extent, but it only works on a single file:

```
    @Echo off 
    set "Total=0" 
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%a in (Server1_Count.txt) do Set /a "Total+=%%a" 
    (echo  %%a >> Server1_CountCompleted.txt Total is %Total%)
```

**I have two problems that I'm struggling with:**

1. I need to create a loop where it will hit every file within the same folder ending with *__Count.txt and then create a new output of *_CountCompleted.txt  All files begin with the different host names and I've been trying to use a wildcard to no avail. *(ie:server1_Count.txt, server2_count.txt is then supposed to generate server1_CountCompleted.txt, server2_CountCompleted)*
2. My current output for this script can only be directed to one file and it generates a new file that looks like below:

> %a  Total is 34

Is there a way to add the hostname (beginning prefix of the file name) to be displayed in the newly generated file, an example:

> server1 Total is 34

Comment: I bet your text data is created by a `find /C "keyword" "file.ext"` command line, am I right? If so, you could use [input redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection-html) to avoid the prefixes and just get the numbers: `find /C "keyword" < "file.ext"`. By the way, `find /C "keyword"` does not return the number of occurrences of `keyword`, it actually returns the *number of lines that contain `keyword`*, so a line containing it multiple times only counts as one...

Comment: I will keep this in mind. These log files will only contain the keyword once per line. So I won't be running into that with this particular issue. Much appreciated regardless.

Comment: Concerning your issue with multiple files: are you trying to use wild-card with `for /F`, like `for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (*.txt) do ( ... )`? this isn't going to work, because `for /F` cannot resolve them, so you need to wrap around a standard `for` loop, like this: `for %%A in ("*.txt") do for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ("%%~A") do ( ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When just using `set /a` no call or delayed expansion is neccessary.

**Hint: when dealing with folders/files possibly containing spaces in the name better use the colon as delims.**

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\01\SO_55461444.cmd
@Echo off
set "Total=0"
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%a in (FILE.txt) do Set /a "Total+=%%a"
echo Total is %Total%
pause
```

Sample output (German locale):

```
> SO_55461444.cmd
Total is 3
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

---

**New variant iterating files `*_count.txt` in given folder:**

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\01\SO_55461444.cmd
@Echo off & SetLocal
:: clear/initialize env vars
set "Total=0"
for /F "delims==" %%A in ('set FileTotal[ 2^>nul') Do Set "%%A="

Pushd "X:\path\Folder" || (Echo couldn't change to folder &Pause&exit /b 1)

Echo Processing folder %CD%
Echo:
:: iterate files in folder
For %%F in (*_count.txt) Do (
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=:" %%A in (
        'Findstr "^-------" "%%F"'
    ) Do Set /A "FileTotal[%%~nF]+=%%A,Total+=%%A"
)

Set FileTotal[
Echo ===================
echo GrandTotal is %Total%
popd
pause
```

sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\01\SO_55461444.cmd
Processing folder Q:\Test\2019\04\02

FileTotal[server1_count]=3
FileTotal[server2_count]=15
===================
GrandTotal is 18
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That without a doubt solves my issue wtih combining the two scripts, however, my biggest predicament is finding a way to run it on multiple files with different file names (the file name starts with the host name) ie: Host1_result.txt.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the hostnames of your thousands of servers, please edit your question to contain sample path / file names / extensions. If the files are in one folder use a simple for (with a different var i.e. %%f) to iterate matching files and nest the above for /f.

Comment: You've gotten me much closer to what I'm looking for, so thank you regardless! I've edited the problem as you've suggested for further clarification.

Comment: Well the edit gives no hint how these files are named or if there are other files in the folder not to process.

Comment: See edited answer which gathers FileTotals in environment vars.

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I'm looking for.