# Parsing hundreds of .txt files that contain numbers, then finding the sum

Tags: powershell, loops, parsing

I have a script that I run on thousands of servers that compiles keywords from logs and outputs how many times they occur within a text file. I use xcopy to snag the logs straight to my box and put them all into the same folder. (IE: Within C:\scripts\ contains server1_results.txt, server2_results.txt, etc) The output looks like this for every individual server:

```
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.001: 0
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.002: 0
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.003: 2
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.004: 0
---------- C:\TEMP\TEXT.005: 1
```

The number after the colon is the number of times a keyword appears within a log. I then use a batch script to parse everything out before the final number and then add the total, this then exports the results into a new text file.

My method works fine, however, I have hundreds of logs and my script only works on one log -- one at a time.

I've been playing with Get-Content but not finding the results I'm looking for.

So, I need a script that will loop and parse every file, and find the sum total of every individual file (server1 will have its own result, server2 will have its own result). It would also be helpful if the script would add the filename to the result. The result I'm looking for:

```
server1_results.txt : 22
```

Comment: What for problems did you had with `Get-Content`? And why cant you add a loop on your own script? If I got you right you just need a loop which reads all the files you have generated? If yes than try something like that: `$OutPut = @(Get-childitem -path "" | foreach {$_.FileName + $(Get-Content -Path $_.FullName)})`

Comment: please upload what you have first, so we can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A powershell script quite similar to my batch answer in
[Parsing multiple text files with alternate file names, finding sum, and then compiling output with Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55461691/6811411)

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\02\SO_55475471.ps1

$Folder = 'X:\path\to\files'

$HashTable = @{}
foreach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter *_count.txt -File)){
  Select-String -Path $File -Pattern '(?<=-{5,}.*)\d+$' | ForEach-Object {
    $HashTable[$File.BaseName]+= [int]$_.Matches[0].Value
  }
}
$HashTable
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\04\02\SO_55475471.ps1

Name                           Value
----                           -----
server1_count                  3
server2_count                  15
```

**PS: Just change `*_count.txt`=> `*_results.txt`**

To get some statistics:

```
> $HashTable.GetEnumerator()|Measure-Object Value -sum -ave -min -max

Count    : 2
Average  : 9
Sum      : 18
Maximum  : 15
Minimum  : 3
Property : Value
```

Comment: Nailed it on the head! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
$Files = (Get-ChildItem c:\scripts\*.txt).FullName
$count=0
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    $thisCount = Get-Content $File
    $Count = $Count + $thisCount
}
"Total Count is: $Count"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will accomplish what you want:

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "C:\scripts\*_results.txt")) {
    $Sum = 0
    switch -regex -file $file
    {
        "[1-9]\d*$" {$sum += $matches[0] -as [int]}
    }
    "{0} : {1}" -f $file.name,$sum
}
```

Do you have any performance objectives?